# paypal webhook notification not received - sandbox mode

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

I'm trying to get notified via webhooks when a simple payment is made, however I don't receive any request from paypal on the specified URL.
Here is what I've done:

1. I have 2 sandbox accounts: Facilitator and Buyer
2. Create an app (sanbox mode) for the facilitator account
3. Add a webhook URL in that app
4. Login into sanbox.paypal.com with the sandbox facilitator username and password
5. Generate a buy now button with a test product
6. Paste the button code on my page and make a purchase with the sanbox Buyer account

In developer dashboard the payment is received if I go to Sandbox -> Notifications: "Notification of Payment Received from test buyer", but the webhook page on my server is not called. I know this because the php script creates a txt file every time the page is called.
Also if I go to *Developer Account -> Webhook Notifications* and select the app I have this message: *You don't have any events for the selected application*

**NOTE: If I add the URL in the webhook simulator everything works great.**

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to connect the app with the buy now button?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webhooks is only used for REST payments. However for Paypal buttons created in PP account, you need to use Paypal IPN. Here is the [guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) for IPN and IPN [script](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/) for your reference.